# Swift Geocode failed with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)"

Tags: swift, geocode

I am trying to get state, city country from zipcode using Geocode. it is working fine in india zip code but not working in USA Zipcode.
Can any one please me any suggestion.

```
enter code here

    guard let zipcode : String = "99501" else {
        print("must enter zipcode")
        return 
    }

    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(zipcode) { (placemarks, error) in
        if let error = error{
            print("Unable to get the location: (\(error))")
        }
        else{
            if let placemarks = placemarks{

                // get coordinates and city
                guard let location = placemarks.first?.location, let city = placemarks.first?.locality else {
                    print("Location not found")
                    return
                }


                print("coordinates: -> \(location.coordinate.latitude) , \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
                print("city: -> \(city)")

                if let country = placemarks.first?.country{
                    print("country: -> \(country)")
                }

                //update UI on main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    //self.countryLbl.text = country
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is india zip code. and using this zipcode working well, but in USA zipcode not working

Comment: Try changing the Region setting of your device to India? Or change the language to an Indian language?

Comment: FWIW, the code 8 is `CLError.geocodeFoundNoResult`. It’s obviously not able to successfully resolve the five digit zip code in the absence of a country code from where you are, though for me (in the US) it successfully resolved to Anchorage.

Comment: Thank you Rob it's solved.i am using my zipcode is "US99501". and it's working